# Did minecraft pe from android is the same with ios?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios, android

Can we transfer minecraft from android to ios with computer? Cause my brother is changing his phone and didnt want to lose his worlds. I want to transfer the minecraft file is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if the world file/code would be the same, but if you want to transfer the worlds, you are going to need acces to the files/ROOT stored on the Iphone (i assume your brother is using an Iphone)
After you gained acces, you have to search the application folder that contains the Minecraft PE files* on the old phone and copy the world files to a folder of your choice. copy the folders from that folder to the folder linked to the minecraft application*. search for a folder called "Worlds" or "Saves" or something like that.
I think that should do the job.
*I dont know where this is located because i do not own a copy of Minecraft PE